# Certifications that involve practical knowledge

Tags: certification, professional-education

After a lot of googling and searches on forums, it was apparent that certificates like CEH and CISSP incorporated a lot of theory in them and were useful as an added for a job.

Are there any certificates that give real-time practice with the system during training or a learning process that includes practical working (certificates that will give working knowledge)?

What about Red Hat certs or Cisco certs?

Comment: OSCP is a good one.

Answer (score 5):

I think one of the most hands on security certifications out there is Offensive Security Certified Professional/Expert. The exam involves executing a penetration test and delivering a report on which you will get quoted. Now this certificate is aimed at attack and penetration testers, if your job is to administer Cisco equipment you should look into CCNAS or CCNPS.

There is also SANS but to be honest they are a bit expensive. The trainings are good though.

Comment: Yeah I read about OSCP and it is indeed very interesting. But the thing is that I am not much acquainted with the info. security field, a beginner if u will. Also I live in India and did not find much of training resources available here. So can you suggest basic or intermediate level courses that can help me build up my knowledge ? Later on when possible I can take up those advanced courses.

Comment: I'd start with the securitytube courses if I were you then. Especially the python,metasploit and Linux ones are pretty good. They are quite cheap as well

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Matasano Crypto Challenges](http://www.matasano.com/articles/crypto-challenges/)? Here's a good review from the [PinBoard Blog](http://blog.pinboard.in/2013/04/the_matasano_crypto_challenges/):

> I mentioned earlier that I thought every web programmer should try
>   their hand at these. It is very illuminating to look at your own web
>   app from the vantage point of an attacker actually writing code. At
>   the very least, you will never be confused about cipher block modes
>   again, or have to worry that someone will ask you to explain how a
>   public key works in an interview. And there is a whole slew of dumb
>   mistakes you will now avoid (replacing them with smarter mistakes that
>   will become the subject matter of challenges 48-96).

Also, Cody Brocious from Accuvan LABS AppSec Team is running the [Breaker 101 course](http://daeken.com/2013-06-11.1_Breaker_101__An_intensive_online_web_security_course.html):

> The majority of the coursework will be styled as a CTF (capture the
>   flag). In essence, you will be breaking from day one and putting these
>   attacks in practice. The exceptions are some of the crypto and the
>   secure architecture/threat modeling portions of the course. These will
>   be graded for your benefit but do not count towards your score.
>
> Exams are largely practical as well, but will be more open-ended, as
>   you will see in real-world security testing.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays certifications such as CEH Practical are really a great start for beginners. It does not carry the burden of OSCP, nor does it come with the excessive theory of its older sibling the CEH(ANSI). It is cheaper than both the OSCP and CEH(ANSI) but sits somewhere in the middle. For hands-on experience and practice for the CEH Practical, please check EC-Council's iLabs platform.

CISSP is good if you have worked for a while and are looking to clinch a managerial role, then you could consider that.